# A Variable representing an area in a definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

[The integral in question](https://gyazo.com/3506a3e786d85c8876bf7b05ba461126)

The homework is already turned in so I won't be getting any credit changing it now but my instructor is adamant about the answer to part B. I just want some confirmation and justification as to what the correct answer is.

As the problem states, the area shaded in blue is represented by A. For part B of the problem, I answered it with A but I got a wrong answer. I asked my instructor about this and he said that the answer is '-A' because the area is under the x-axis, thus needing a '-' to make it a negative number. However, I think that it is wrong. I think the answer should be 'A' because the area, as a a whole which is a negative number, is already represent by 'A' so therefore, it shouldn't need a negative in front of it.

Is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: There is a difference between the integral of a function and the area under the function. The area under the function equals the integral of the absolute value of the function.

Comment: There are two possible points of view. One can view area below the axis as negative. I think (and your instructor agrees) that this is not reasonable, that area is inherently non-negative. But the *integral* for sure is negative. So I would say that if the area is $A$, the integral is $-A$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why is it correct to think of the area as inherently non-negative?

Comment: If you want to paint it red, you will need a positive amount of paint. More abstractly, the area of a region is independent of its location.  If you push the region up by $50$, its area should not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, in elementary calculus courses, area below the $x$-axis is taken to be negative.

But very much more often, one takes the point of view that the area of a region ought to be independent of its location, that congruent regions have the same area. Thus the area $A$ of your region should be unchanged if we move the region up by $50$, putting it fully above the $x$-axis.  To put it another way, the area of a region should remain unchanged if the $x$-axis is moved.

But the integral of the post is definitely negative, and its value is $-A$.